# How to minify a source file (Javascript) into a minify file using uglifyjs-webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

I want to minify my files using uglifyjs-webpack.

For example I have a source file `core/js/test` and want to minify it and send it to `min/js/test`.

Just using a source and respective output, how do I use it with webpack.

Comment: How is `means.org` relevant to your question? How does your current webpack configuration file look like? What is the problem with your current webpack setup?

Comment: currently, I don't have any web pack setup in my application. In mean the way of assigning the client files is different, So Just in case I am mentioning it might be of any help to understand my working environment

Comment: When you ask a question on SO you should show a minimal research effort. In your case this means that you should include your webpack configuration file, which shows your attempt to include the webpack uglifyjs plugin. And an explanation what does not work.

Comment: Okay I will try researching on this, thanks fo your kind suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often just use the `optimization: {minimize: true}` option ([see this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-minimize)) since webpack 4.

```
const path = require("path"); 

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "/origin/main.js",
  output: {
      path: path.resolve("./min/js/"),
      filename: "test.js"
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
};
```

However, webpack still allows you to override the default implementation using the `UglifyjsWebpackPlugin`. I'd advise you to have a look at the docs in [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-minimizer), they seem to explain it quite alright.

Comment: This solution seems promising but, could you explain how to use this in my file, since I'm a newbie in using web pack.

Comment: As far as I can think of, I'd need quite a lot to try and explain you in more detail. This is basically the bulk of a very simplistic `webpack.config.js` file, which'd set up  its processing. As @t.niese says above, I really think you should first go through an effort of reasearching and maybe sparing some time for tutorialing too. [Some config help](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) and [simple getting started](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/)

Comment: Okay, I will check the resources on web pack and then I will use your solution. I will get back with the response thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I have done a bit research on this and tried your solution, It worked like magic.

Answer (score -1):

You might like this web site. It will help you to minify.
[minifier](https://javascript-minifier.com/)

Comment: while it's probably a good site, it doesn't answer the question.